# Zend View Helper formMultiCheckbox, add css class

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, view-helpers

`<?php echo $this->formMultiCheckbox($this->form->options->getFullyQualifiedName(), $this->form->options->getValue(),
    null, array('1' => $this->form->options->getMultiOption('1'))); ?>`

I have something like this, I want to add a css class to it. How could I do that with this helper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the class name with the third parameter (`$attribs`):

```
<?php echo
$this->formMultiCheckbox($this->form->options->getFullyQualifiedName(), 
$this->form->options->getValue(), array('class' => 'myclass'), array('1' =>
$this->form->options->getMultiOption('1'))); ?>
```

This will add the html attribute `class="myclass"` to the checkbox.